# Como funciona o buffer usando printf e scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, buffer, printf

Utilizando o `printf`, quando faço:

```
printf("\n\tQualquer coisa\n");
```

Ele insere isso primeiro em um buffer e depois imprime na tela (saída padrão) ?

Utilizando o `scanf` com o formato `%c`, ele captura do buffer caractere a caractere. Mas e quando utilizo o formato `%s` ? Ele para quando encontra um espaço ou enter, mas ele deixa esse enter ou espaço no buffer ? Se sim, como pode ler algo do buffer e não capturá-lo ?

E no caso destes `scanf` :

```
scanf("%c\n", &caracter);
scanf("%s\n", string);
```

Estes `scanf` acima lêem do buffer um caractere (para `%c`) e uma string (para `%s`) e retiram do buffer o próximo enter ? O que acontece ? O que significa estes caracteres dentro das aspas ? Sempre imaginei que no `scanf`, o primeiro parâmetro era somente os formatos a serem lidos.

Gostaria que pudessem me explicar minuciosamente, pois em aula e em livros, as explicações são supérfluas, e sei que não é bem simples o funcionamento disso.
Caso existir alguma documentação que relate bem o comportamento disso, por favor, me passe o link, pois procurei na standard do C e não encontrei.

Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigo o problema é que ao ler uma string com mais de uma palavra (com espaços) ela para de ler armazenando apenas a primeira palavra. Um exemplo seria a string "Minha casa", caso usemos a sintaxe acima ele apenas armazenará a palavra "Minha", parando ao encontrar o espaço.

O que podemos fazer para corrigir este erro é forçar o scanf ler a string até encontrar o [enter], para isto devemos inserir o seguinte código:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", string);
```

Os parametros passados entre as aspas do scanf ou do printf são propriedades de leitura ou saída que o C te disponibiliza. No seu código ele apenas está informando que vai ler uma string e dar uma quebra de linha após a variável.

```
\n = quebra de linha
```

Para saber como isso é amplo, o exemplo abaixo irá ler todas as letras do alfabeto ignorando números digitados!

```
scanf("%[a-z A-Z]s");
```

Comment: Sim, já vi isso em muitos livros, mas sem o `s` depois do fecha colchetes. O que este `s` influencia ? E como o buffer funciona neste caso, ele lê até o enter e deixa o enter no buffer ou captura-o ?

Comment: Então qual é realmente sua dúvida? abraços

Comment: Como é que o buffer reage com os formatos do scanf `%c %s %[^\n]` ?

Comment: com %c você pega 1 char, com %s tu pega string ignorando os espaços como falei acima. %[^\n] você pega espaço em branco sem qualquer outro valor, se por acaso precisa pegar string ou inteiro você não consegue apenas com isso %[^\n]. Se você usar scanf("%s\n", &string); com & você se refere a um endereço, onde a string vai ter que ser declarada dessa forma string[50] por exemplo. Abraços

Comment: Amigo, primeiro que não respondeu a minha pergunta, segundo que está me "ensinando" como utilizar ponteiros de maneira errada. O que está fazendo em `scanf("%s\n", &string);` é passar o endereço do endereço para `scanf`, neste caso, como declarou `string[50]`, `string` (puro, sem &), já é o endereço.

Comment: Acabei de compilar e tirei um print para te mostrar http://i.imgur.com/DxPVoco.png . Talvez, caso queira colocar o `&`, você pode utilizar assim: `&string[0]` que para vetores unidimensionais é o mesmo que `string`.