# Converter um array de char para um array de ints

Tags: c

Basicamente eu estou a tentar guardar uma sequencia de inteiros. Usei um array de char para quando der como input uma sequencia de 21 números ele assumir como uma string e logo após guardar cada número em cada espaço do array de char.
Depois queria copiar esse array de char para um array de int. O problema é que quando dou como

*input*: **123443211234567890127**

o programa dá me como *output*: **-3812344321123456789012**

Alguém me pode ajudar a resolver aquele -38?

```
void testa_nib () {

    int i,j=0,h=0,res=0;
    char str[21];
    int nib[21];

    for(i=0;i<=21;i++){
        scanf("%c",&str[i]);

    }
    for (h=0; h<21 ; h++) {
        char s;
        int tmp;
        s=str[h];
        tmp =  s - '0' ;
        printf("%d",tmp);
        nib[h]=tmp;
    }

int main() {

    testa_nib();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aquilo é uma quebra de linha, um `Chr( 10 ) - '0'` dá `-38` ( o `\n` é o caractere 10 da tabela ASCII, que é incorporada na Unicode também, e em praticamente todas as páginas de código modernas)- faltou sanitização na entrada de dados.

Comment: mas como é q isso acontece se nao tenho nenhum char (10)?

Comment: No scanf deve ter pego algum. Experimente fazer um print em hexadecimal como debug, para ter certeza

Comment: pode me explicar como faço isso? ainda estou a aprender c

Comment: Teste assim: `scanf(" %c",&str[i]);` - com um espaço antes do % - Isso faz com que o `scanf` remova caracteres em branco, estou tentando localizar se já existe um post explicando isso.

Comment: com o espaço antes do % já deu, muito obrigado, mas pode me dizer porque é q isto aconteceu?

Comment: Postei uma resposta com mais detalhes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O valor `-38` já dá uma boa indicação do problema.

Nesta linha aqui você faz com que os caracteres de `'0'` a `'9'` sejam convertidos em um número de zero a nove:

```
tmp =  s - '0' ;
```

Só que se passa algum caractere não numérico na sua *string*, por acaso uma quebra de linha, que é o caractere 10 da tabela ASCII (também incorporada em outras tabelas mais modernas), isso aqui dá `-38`:

```
tmp =  10 - '0';  // 0 tem o valor 48 na tabela ASCII
```

Se quer eliminar caracteres em branco em um `scanf`, adicione um espaço em branco antes da `%`:

```
scanf(" %c",&str[i]);
//     ^- aqui
```

Leitura complementar:

> [O que acontece em uma conversão de um char para um int?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3760/70)

> [Qual a diferença entre "NULL", "\0" e 0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177619/70)

> [Como funciona o buffer usando printf e scanf?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39642/70)

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou imenso!